# how to get specific key's value in freemarker

Tags: java, freemarker

I have following HashMap:

```
 Map<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
 hashMap.put("type", "message");
```

I wrote a switch statement in freemarker template:

```
    <#switch hashMap.get("type")>
        <#case "message">
            <p>Message type</p>
            <#default>
                <p>Nothing</p>
    </#switch>
```

But when I execute the code, I am getting exception:

---

```
freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: [... Exception message was already printed; see it above ...]
    at freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException.getInstance(InvalidReferenceException.java:134)
    at freemarker.core.UnexpectedTypeException.newDesciptionBuilder(UnexpectedTypeException.java:80)
    at freemarker.core.UnexpectedTypeException.<init>(UnexpectedTypeException.java:43)
    at freemarker.core.NonHashException.<init>(NonHashException.java:49)
    at freemarker.core.Dot._eval(Dot.java:48)
    at freemarker.core.Expression.eval(Expression.java:81)
    at freemarker.core.MethodCall._eval(MethodCall.java:58)
    at freemarker.core.Expression.eval(Expression.java:81)
    at freemarker.core.EvalUtil.compare(EvalUtil.java:111)
    at freemarker.core.SwitchBlock.accept(SwitchBlock.java:67)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:326)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:332)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.process(Environment.java:305)
    at freemarker.template.Template.process(Template.java:378)
    at com.comp.www.reports.FreeMarkerReport.main(FreeMarkerReport.java:70)
```

Can Anyone please point at what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you set hashmap as your model? In any case in your switch should be just `<#switch type>`

Comment: Another remark : You forgot  `<#break>` after your case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
hashMap.get("type")
```

use

```
hashMap[type]
```

Comment: That should be `hashMap.type`. Or, `hashMap["type"]`, though that's longer. `hashMap[type]` without the quotation marks looks up with the key that's the value of the `type` variable.